# Libref function in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am new to SAS and I am trying to decode a SAS code. In the beginning of the script the codes has a line that says -

```
%let sales=sale_q;
%if (%sysfunc(libref(sales))) %then %do;
    libname sales "/data/raw/sales/sales_a";
```

I have three data files - sales_q for quarterly sales, sales_a for annual sales and sales_m for monthly sales.

My code sets the library sales to use quarterly sales data. What does the %if statement do?
I searched about the libref function and found out that it just verifies the existence of a library path name. But I don't understand the need to use the IF statement.

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS Documentation is your friend.

A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sas%20libref%20function) has led me to [LIBREF Function page of the SAS documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212077.htm)

It describes `LIBREF` function as :

> specifies the libref to be verified. In a DATA step, libref can be a
>   character expression, a string enclosed in quotation marks, or a DATA
>   step variable whose value contains the libref. In a macro, libref can
>   be any expression
>
> The LIBREF function returns 0 if the libref has been assigned, or
>   returns a nonzero value if the libref has not been assigned.

So, to answer your question, The `%if` statement is checking to see if `sales` has been assigned as a library references or not. If not `%then %do` part will assign `"/data/raw/sales/sales_a"` to `sales`.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I did go through the SAS documentation on this function but I wasn't sure if I got it right. I needed someone's confirmation on how it works. THanks

Answer (score 0):

The libref is pointing towards a specific "physical" path and can be assigned and unassigned.

A libref may also be e.g an excel spreadsheet, and in that case - assigning and unssigning librefs is important.